# can't analyze output from txt file python - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, string, twitter, text

I am trying to learn simple text analysis using Twitter data. Ultimately I want to search for tweets with certain strings, and may analyze the favorite count for them. But right now I am trying to do simple printing and searching of my txt file.

I have figured out how to download the data and save it to a .txt file, but then I can seem to analyze it. I am using Python 3.5.2 on a Mac. I am writing the code in TextWrangler and having it run in Terminal.

I have looked at other documentation on this issue, but I can't understand it.

Here is my code.

```
import tweepy
import sys
import re
consumer_key = 'xxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxx'
access_token = 'xxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api =  tweepy.API(auth) 
api.statuses_lookup('realdonaldtrump', include_entities=True, trim_user=False, map_= False) 
tweetslist = []
print (api.statuses_lookup) 
trump_tweets = api.user_timeline('realdonaldtrump', count=100)
sys.stdout = open('trump_tweet_output.txt', 'w')
for tweet in trump_tweets:
    print (tweet.text)
sys.stdout.close()

##the above code works fine, creates a .txt file with tweet text

##but when I run the below-- (or any other command to analyze the file)

f = open('trump_tweet_output.txt')
line = f.readline()
print (line)
f(close)

##I get: 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'
```

Comment: It's because you're messing with `sys.stdout`.  When you're writing to the file, do `f=open('trump_tweet_output.txt', 'w')` then `f.write(..)` to write to it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from this line:

```
sys.stdout = open('trump_tweet_output.txt', 'w')
```

because further down you then close this file which ends up closing the stdout stream.

I would recommend that instead of reassigning `sys.stdout`, you just write to the file.

```
with open('trump_tweet_output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tweet in trump_tweets:
        f.write(tweet + '\n')
```

Then when you are trying to read the file, you can just write:

```
with open('trump_tweet_output.txt') as f:
    print(f.readline())
```